# Dojo + WCF Data Services + OData

Tags: dojo, wcf-data-services, odata

Is there any module in Dojo which helps to work with WCF Data Services using OData protocol in JSON format? Something that is similar to dojo.store.JsonRest.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have seen, no.

In this post, one developer was working with Odata and dojo but I haven't found any follow ups on his work.

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/dojo-OData-td2055388.html;cid=1324566111185-564#a2065855